# Generics friendly Type Handler map

Tags: java, java-8, generics

I'm trying to make a "registry" of handlers that return a specific type

```
public class HandlerRegistry {
   Map<Class<?>, Handler<?>> handlers;

   <T> void setHandler(Class<T> type, Handler<? extends T> handler) {
      handlers.put(type, handler);
   }

   <T> T handle(Class<T> type, HandlerArgument arg) {
      Handler<? extends T> handler = getHandler(type);

      return handler.handle(arg);
   } 

   <T> Handler<? extends T> getHandler(Class<T> type) {
      // warning produced here "uses unchecked or unsafe operations."
      return (Handler<? extends T>)handlers.get(type);
   }
}
```

I know that this particular cast will never fail at runtime, but other than using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is there a way to tell the compiler that this is indeed safe?

I'm using Java 8 specifically, if there is a more elegant way to do what I want in 8.

Comment: In method `getHandler(Class<T> type)`, `handlers.get(type, handler);` should change to `handlers.get(type);`

Comment: Oops, right.  I blame sleep deprivation. I'll fix.

Comment: So, it looks like I was correct in thinking there wasn't an "elegant" solution, just pushing the "problem" to a different level.  Java Generics aren't C++ templates, after all.

Comment: Somewhere in here, I think, is an elegant solution, struggling to get out.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, an unchecked operation is unavoidable in this case. The best thing you can do is to isolate the unchecked operation and guard it with a safe test. One proven solution is to wrap the instance in a holder instance which encapsulates the unchecked operation and enforces the pre-check:

```
class HandlerRegistry {
    private static class Holder<T> {
        private final Class<T>   type;
        private final Handler<? extends T> handler;
        Holder(Class<T> c, Handler<? extends T> h) {
            type=Objects.requireNonNull(c);
            handler=h;
        }
        <U> Holder<U> as(Class<U> expected) {
            if(type!=expected)
                throw new ClassCastException();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Holder<U> h=(Holder)this;
            return h;
        }
        public Handler<? extends T> getHandler() {
            return handler;
        }
    }
    Map<Class<?>, Holder<?>> handlers;

    <T> void setHandler(Class<T> type, Handler<? extends T> handler) {
        handlers.put(type, new Holder<>(type, handler));
    }
    <T> T handle(Class<T> type, HandlerArgument arg) {
        return getHandler(type).handle(arg);
    }
    <T> Handler<? extends T> getHandler(Class<T> type) {
        return handlers.get(type).as(type).getHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: This "Holder" is not really necessary, is it? (I can't see what benefit it brings: In either case, one will have one unchecked cast - be it in `Registry#get` or in `Holder#as`...)

Comment: The `Holder` holds the `type` as a `Class` instance and checks whether they match before performing the unchecked operation, so it guarantees that only correct casts can be performed. Unlike map entries which do not enforce any relationship between key and value, you can create `Holder`s only with an appropriate pair of `Class<…>` object and `Handler<…>` and can retrieve the `Handler` only with the appropriate `Class<…>` object. Performing the type cast within `getHandler` can’t provide such strong check.

Comment: The map can not assert this type safety, but the registry class itself can do this - and it already *does* this, in the code that was posted in the question: One can not add a wrong type to the registry, because the only method that adds handlers is equipped with generics. The "Handler" just seems to pull this check "one level deeper", and I don't see any advantage in that (only the (slight?) disadvantage of "more code").

Comment: @Marco13: the point is that the class `HandlerRegistry` can evolve, grow, having more than one `setHandler` method, etc. So `getHandler` can be sure about the correctness only if it assumes that *all* methods modifying the map are correct and that there is no place where the map can escape to the outside. In contrast, the `Holder` is immutable, `private` and not meant to evolve. Using the `Holder` you will notice, if the map got corrupted, instead of having heap pollution spreading to the outside.

Comment: Sure it can grow and evolve. But the same person who is responsible for the registry is also responsible for the Holder. I see your point, but am not sure whether assumptions about future evolution can "justify" introducing a class that is plainly not necessary (and not beneficial) for the scenario that was described until now. But maybe one can just consider this as some sort of far-sightedness, and leave it to the asker whether he will use it or not...

Answer (score 2):

This setup is reminiscent of Bloch's *Typesafe Heterogeneous Container* idiom from *Effective Java, Item 29*. This is also described in Neal Gafter's article on [Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

The warning occurs in this snippet of code (note minor correction):

```
    <T> Handler<? extends T> getHandler(Class<T> type) {
        // warning produced here "uses unchecked or unsafe operations."
        return (Handler<? extends T>)handlers.get(type);
    }
```

The code from *Effective Java* (also in Gafter's article) stores instances of type `T` as map values. It avoids unchecked warnings by using

```
        return type.cast(map.get(type));
```

That is, it uses `Class.cast()` to do the casting. This has a return value of the right type, so you don't have to cast it. But of course it just does the cast internally, and it's annotated with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. The messiness is still there, but at least it's covered up.

This doesn't work in your case, at least not directly, because the map values aren't of type `T`, they're of type `Handler<? extends T>`. It would be nice if we could write a class literal for this, something like `Handler<? extends T>.class`, but this doesn't work.

One could attempt to use Gafter's super type tokens for this. Basically create an anonymous subclass of `Handler<T>` and call `getClass()` on it:

```
    <T> Handler<? extends T> getHandler(Class<T> type) {
        Class<? extends Handler<T>> clazz = new Handler<T>() {
            public T handle(HandlerArgument arg) { return null; }
        }.getClass();
        return clazz.cast(handlers.get(type));
    }
```

However, this **DOES NOT WORK**. This gives us a `Class` object of the right static type, and then we can call its `cast()` method to do the casting for us. This avoids the unchecked warning. However, as Holger pointed out in this comments, this **cannot work** at runtime, since the handler provided by the caller is never an instance of this anonymous subclass. Indeed, this always fails with `ClassCastException` at runtime.

This is clearly not a solution. However, it is a little bit interesting in that it does avoid the compiler warnings. I'll leave it here since it might help point the way to an actual solution.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? The `Class` instance retrieved by invoking `getClass()` on an instance of the anonymous inner class represents the anonymous inner class, so `clazz.cast(…)` *must* fail as it is impossible that the instance retrieved from the `handlers` map is an instance of that anonymous inner class.

Comment: My answer meanly deals with inheritance (a problem too), but this got it _almost_ (?) right, and was well-founded, a pleasure in citing references. Maybe a `getDeclaringClass()` or so.

Comment: getClass() returns Class<?>, so the clazz.cast results in the same warning in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is a bit of a problem too, using a map from class to container.
A mapping can hardly deal with inheritance. And in fact I think you got the generic `? extends T` wrong. But let's look

```
/** Handles T or children of T. */
public class Handler<T> {
    public final Class<T> type;

    Handler(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public class HandlerRegistry {

    private final Map<Class<?>, Handler<?>> handlers = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void setHandler(Class<T> type, Handler<T> handler) {
        handlers.put(type, handler);
    }

    public <T> Handler<? super T> getHandler(Class<T> type) {
        Handler<?> handler = handlers.get(type);
        if (handler != null) {
            Handler<T> ht = new Handler<>(type);
            return ht.getClass().cast(handler);
        }
        if (type.isPrimitive() || type == Object.class) {
            return null;
        }
        return getHandler(type.getSuperclass());
    }
}

class NumberHandler extends Handler<Number> {
    NumberHandler() {
        super(Number.class);
    }
}

class BigDecimalHandler extends Handler<BigDecimal> {
    BigDecimalHandler() {
        super(BigDecimal.class);
    }
}

    HandlerRegistry hreg = new HandlerRegistry();
    hreg.setHandler(Number.class, new NumberHandler());

    Handler<? super BigDecimal> h = hreg.getHandler(BigDecimal.class);
    System.out.println("Handler: " + h.getClass().getName());
```

> Handler: ... .NumberHandler

I think many people will object against this design on the unusual `super` usage; a heritance issue.

On the actual problem:

`ht` is an instance which the compiler associates with `Handler<actual-T>`. Hence `ht.getClass()` is indeed for the compiler `Handler<T>`.

So `ht.getClass().cast(...)` will cast to Handler and be assumed Handler`.
Unsafe as long as type erasure is used.