# Find specific object in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

Currently have an issue getting a specific object in an arraylist. So I have multiple classes that implements the same interface, and I create objects of the different classes. The problem is that I don't know how to differentiate the classes in the arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Interface> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    addInterface(new interfaceA());
    addInterface(new interfaceB());
    addInterface(new interfaceC());

}

public static void addInterface(Interface foo) {
    arraylist.add(foo);
}
```

Let say that I want to get `interfaceA()`, I could call it by `arraylist.get(0)` but I don't want to hardcode it. Each class has the same methods but the code is different.

Comment: why do you need this specific object?

Comment: Lot of problems with the above code: 1. interface is a reserved keyword and can not be used as a variable `Interface interface` 2. You can not instantiate an interface `new interfaceA()`.

Comment: One, consider a design pattern, such as a `Chain of Responsibility` and remove the specific attempt to retrieve it; allow each implementation to decide it wants to handle the request or not. If not possible, what are the criteria by which you will select? Perhaps a `Map` with the appropriate key. Finally, consider looking at this question [Type Handler Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837124/generics-friendly-type-handler-map) which, leaving aside the generics and discussion on Exceptins, shows something similar, which is a registry.

Comment: If all those classes have overridden equals correct you can just use the methods [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) or [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.Object-) to find the indexes of specific object

Comment: @TimCastelijns each class has the same methods but the code of the methods are different from each other

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I only used `interface` as an example

Comment: @JayLee that's not what I asked. If you care about this difference in implementation, why are you putting them together in the same list?

Comment: Simply, if you need a specific implementation of an interface, don't throw it into a collection where you lose the actual type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `Map` instead of a `List`. In this case an [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) is a good fit.

```
interface Thing {

}

IdentityHashMap<Class<? extends Thing>, Thing> things = new IdentityHashMap<>();

class ThingA implements Thing {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ThingA{}";
    }
}

class ThingB implements Thing {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ThingB{}";
    }
}

class ThingC implements Thing {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ThingC{}";
    }
}

public void registerThing(Thing thing) {
    things.put(thing.getClass(), thing);
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    registerThing(new ThingA());
    registerThing(new ThingB());
    registerThing(new ThingC());

    System.out.println(things.get(ThingB.class));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter using a predicate, by checking runtime classes:

```
List<Interface> interfaceAList = arraylist.stream()
                         .filter(e -> InterfaceA.class.isInstance(e))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Interface getInterfaceA(List<Interface> interfaces) {
    for (Interface i : interfaces) {
        if (i instanceof InterfaceA)
            return i;
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some text to describe how your answer would help to solve the problem.